# Outputting a triangle

Tags: c++

Enter an odd value greater than zero -- I understand how to do that.

Print out a triangle that looks like the following if 5 is entered:

```
54321
 432
  3
```

If 11 is entered:

```
10987654321
 098765432
  9876543
 and so on
```

I see that we must divide the input by 10 and print the remainder but I'm having trouble printing the countdown.

```
for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) 
  i = i - 1;
```

Comment: `for (i = n; i >= 1; i--) ` is equivalent to "Hello world" for your tiny project :P You tried only this ?

Comment: Haha...yeah, I know. I'm tired :p

Comment: @user1034672: Then give up for now and try again later. Either that, or tell what kind of difficulty you're having.

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop (start at 0), and on each iteration print a substring from i to string.length()-1 an use the set width to increase the indent, following code below:

```
string num = "10987654321";

for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); ++i){
   cout << setw(i) << right << num.substr(i, num.length()-i) << endl;
}
```

This should give you your desired output. (if "<< right <<" doesn't work, swap "right" with "left")

**ALSO**
you need to include iomanip to use setw()

Comment: I know I wasn't clear at all; there will be an integer input. Also, can't use object methods (like `num.length`) and `setw`. It looks like I'll need a nested `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
int num = 10987654321;
int numSpaces = 1;

cout << num << endl;

for (int i = 0; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numSpaces; j++)
    {
         cout << " ";
    } 

    cout << num % 10 << endl;

    num = num / 10;

    numSpaces++;
}
```

Voila a beautiful triangle :)